# Hölder 1/2 condition for curve

Tags: real-analysis

Does there exist a continuous  map $\gamma:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^n$ s.t. $$|\gamma(x)-\gamma(y)| \ge |x-y|^{\frac 1 2}  $$ for all $x,y \in [0,1]$?

Comment: $\ge$ ??????????????

Comment: @ Taxi Driver: Could you clarify your emotional remark in details? I am not any psychic.

Comment: I think Taxi Driver is asking whether you meant 
$$
|\gamma(x)-\gamma(y)| \le |x-y|^{\frac 1 2}
$$

Comment: @ robjohn: I think my question is clear: Does there exist a curve not satisfying the $1/2$ Lipschitz condition in any point of $[0,1]$?

Comment: @user64494 same as what robjohn is saying

Comment: @user64494: the condition you've stated is not the negation of the Hölder $\frac12$ condition; so no, your question is not clearly what you've just said.

Comment: @ robjohn: You are right. The question is related to the $1/2$Lipschitz condition.

Comment: @user64494: to be pedantic, the [Lipschitz condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity) has exponent $1$. The [Hölder-$\alpha$ condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder_condition) uses different exponents.

Comment: @ robjohn: Thank you. It has been fixed.

Comment: @user64494: I hope you realize that this condition is *not* the Hölder-$\frac12$ condition or even its negation. For a curve to satisfy this condition, if this is  even possible, it would need to be truly pathological.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is such a function. You should be able to construct one explicitly by an appropriate modification of the [Koch snowflake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koch_snowflake) construction, although I don't want to work through the details.

In fact, much more is true. Take any metric space $(X,d)$ which satisfies a certain finite-dimensionality condition called "doubling". (This means that, for some constant $N$, every ball of radius $r$ can be covered by at most $N$ balls of radius $r/2$.)

Now take any $0<\alpha <1$. Then there is a constant $C\geq 1$, a positive integer $n$, and a map $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ which satisfies
$$ C^{-1} d(x,y)^\alpha \leq |f(x) - f(y)| \leq Cd(x,y)^\alpha.$$

This is called Assouad's embedding theorem.

What does this have to do with your question? Well, let $(X,d)$ be $[0,1]$ with the usual metric given by $|\cdot|$. This is a doubling metric space, so by Assouad's theorem (with $\alpha=1/2$) we get a map $f:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ satisfying
$$ C^{-1} |x-y|^{1/2} \leq |f(x) - f(y)| \leq C|x-y|^{1/2}.$$

If you just rescale $f$ by a factor of $C$, you get
$$ |x-y|^{1/2} \leq |f(x) - f(y)| \leq C^2|x-y|^{1/2},$$
which in particular is what you wanted.

Comment: Could you give an accessible reference to the Assouad's theorem?

Comment: I would like to note that the Assouad's theorem claims the existence of the dimension $n$. This means that its application does not produce the answer to the question (where $n$ is arbitrary). I am not able to construct the required function, using the Koch flake.

Comment: A proof of Assouad's theorem can be found in Heinonen's book Lectures on Analysis on Metric Spaces.

Comment: It was not really clear from your question whether $n$ was meant to be arbitrary or whether any $n$ sufficed. Assouad's theorem gives such curves for all $n$ sufficiently large. Maybe my remark about the snowflake was a bit ambitious. If you would like such a curve for $n=2$, it must have the property that the image of every sub-arc has positive Lebesgue measure; such curves exist (see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/24264/a-question-about-the-osgood-curve) but I'm not sure whether the construction referenced there satisfies your condition.

Comment: @ GCD: Could you give a reference to the so called Assouad theorem in the book "Lectures on Analysis on Metric Spaces" by Juha Heinonen , indicating pages and number of this Theorem: Juha Heinonen uses notation like Preposition 3.19. Because in the question under consideration n is not restricted by the existsence quantor, it should be understood as an arbitrary positive integer number.

Comment: It is Theorem 12.2 in Heinonen's book. This was merely the reference I know; I'm sure that it can be found in other places, besides Assouad's original paper of course.

Comment: Unfortunately, [Theorem 12.2](http://rapidshare.com/files/3452925292/Theorem%2012.2.docx) does not coincide with the statement in your answer.

Comment: Yes, Theorem 12.2 in your link to Heinonen's book is exactly what I have said, just in different words. Try reading the text for a discussion--I don't plan on writing a full exposition here. I hope you find a satisfactory answer to your question, whether using my thoughts above or otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

While Heinonen's exposition of Assouad's theorem is excellent, one should not forget the original 1983 paper by Assouad, [Plongements lipschitziens dans $\mathbb R^n$](https://eudml.org/doc/87452). Proposition 4.4 answers your question in a more general form. I restate it below, changing terminology to make it self-contained:

> Let $k\ge 1$ be an integer, and  $p\in (0,1)$. Suppose $n>1/p$ is an integer. Then there exists a map $f:[0,1]^k\to \mathbb R^n$ such that 
>   $$c|x-y|^p \le |f(x)-f(y)|\le C|x-y|^p \tag1$$
>   for all $x,y\in [0,1]^k$, with some positive constants $c$ and $C$.

You can take $k=1$, $p=1/2$, and $n=3$. Then multiply $f$ by a constant to get $c=1$.

As GCD hinted, the construction by Assouad is an   $n$-dimensional form of von Koch snowflake.

It is known that $f$ as in (1) does not exist for $n=1/p$ (in particular, when $n=2$ and $p=1/2$). Indeed, (1) implies that the range of $f$ must be a *porous* set and therefore its $n$-dimensional measure must be zero; when $n=1/p$ the latter is incompatible with the lower bound in (1). See [Porous sets and quasisymmetric maps](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1987-299-02/S0002-9947-1987-0869219-8/) by Väisälä.

The above paragraph leaves open the question of whether you can take $n=2$ if you only want the lower bound in (1) (plus continuity of $f$). I do not know the answer, but suspect it is negative.

One more reference: [Geometric embeddings of metric spaces](http://www.math.jyu.fi/research/reports/rep90.pdf) by Heinonen, specifically Chapter 3.

Comment: For $n = 2$, the answer is indeed negative (https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.acta/1485889215)